# How can a single item picklist for a lead be mapped to a multi-select account picklist

Tags: picklist, map, multi-select

It is a long story as to why (related to our sales process and marketing automation system), but I need to figure out a way to map a single select picklist in a lead to a multi-select picklist in an account.

It can't be done by default, but is there a way to override that?

Answer (score 2):

The only way to do this is with apex, either a visualforce page for lead conversion or a trigger. Here is a handy method for adding to a multiselect field:

```
private String AddToMultiselect(string MultiselectValue, string AddedValue) {  

    string NewMultiselectString = ''; 

    Set<string> MultiselectValueSet = new Set<string>();
    if( MultiselectValue != null ) {
        NewMultiselectString = ';' + MultiselectValue;
        MultiselectValueSet.addAll( MultiSelectValue.split(';') );
    }

    if (addedValue != null) {
        for( string newValue : AddedValue.split(';') ) {
            if ( newValue != null && !MultiselectValueSet.contains(newValue) ) {
                NewMultiselectString += ';' + newValue;     
                MultiselectValueSet.add(newValue);
            }
        }
    }

    return (NewMultiselectString == '') ? null : NewMultiselectString.substring(1); 
}
```

Comment: You could use a database trigger to pull the value from the lead as well. Visualforce would be overkill for such a small ticket item.

Comment: I'll adjust my answer, I wasn't aware that a trigger could fire on lead conversion

Comment: Here's an improvement for your example function, too:

`string addToMultiselect(string msValue, string addValue) { 
 msValue = String.isBlank(msValue)? '': msValue; 
 string[] values = msValue.split(';'); 
 values.add(addValue); 
 Set<String> uniValues = new Set<String>(values), blankVals = new Set<String> { null, '' }; 
 uniValues.removeAll(blankVals); 
 values = new list<string>(uniValues);
 return string.join(values,';');
}`

Comment: [Understanding Lead Conversion](https://na14.salesforce.com/help/doc/en/leads_notes.htm), the section about triggers.